# AzureAD and ADAL not supporing lower version Android and Chrome

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory

I am using Android version 4.1(Jelly Bean) for testing and am using paid AzureAD acct.
The code below allows me to get Sign in Page for entering email Address
The problem : 
After enter email addr and hit next button:
- I got the "Web page Not available"
- By right, it should give me: Sign in with your organization acct.

What the problem?
ADAL does not support lower Android version and chrome? What version of Android and chrome supported?

```
public static string ApplicationID = "xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx";
 public static string tenanturl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx";
 public static string ReturnUri = "http://AppName";
    
 public static string GraphResourceUri = "https://graph.microsoft.com";
 public static AuthenticationResult AuthenticationResult = null;
  var data = await DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>()
  .Authenticate(App.tenanturl, App.GraphResourceUri, App.ApplicationID, App.ReturnUri);
```

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: the error message is pretty clear - *instead sign in with your organisational account*. Use the organisational account and not your personal account. More info on different account types [here](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/09/15/cleaning-up-the-azure-ad-and-microsoft-account-overlap/) and [here](http://www.brucebnews.com/2016/06/finding-your-way-through-microsofts-maze-of-work-and-personal-accounts/)

Comment: No. I am using all the correct settings and I still get this!

Comment: Does this sound like what you're running into? https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/issues/623

Comment: @MilkBottle Gingerbread is the min version supported by ADAL. What code are you using for the AcquireToken call?